# Custom View, continues to pass on events?

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event

I have a ListView.  Inside the cells, I have a custom view. (You can draw in it.)

When drawing, I turn off scrolling of the list ..

```
    theListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
            if ( STATE.weAreDrawoning )
                {
                return true;
                // so, do not forward and hence do not scroll the list
                }
            else
                {
                return false;
                }
            }
        return false;
        }
    });
```

That's fine.  But strangely, up-down touching in the custom View, is **still passed on** to the list and makes it scroll.

```
public class AmazingCustomView extends View
{
blah
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
        blah

        return true;
        }
}
```

notice in the custom view onTouchEvent is returning true (I also tried false! :) )

but the motion events appear to be still passed on .. what gives??

Is there another "on .. something" I'm missing in the custom view?  Sorry, new to Android and lame. Thanks!

PS, I tried turning on "clickable" on the xml of the custom view, didn't help  :O

--

## Worse ...

I've just realised ALL controls in the ListView, say buttons, still "pass on scrolling"

I fear the system I use above for turning off scrolling is just no good.  :/

## important...

For anyone googling to here.  The only real way I've found to turn off scrolling on an android listView ...

danosipov.com/?p=604

(don't forget to separately turn off your pull-to-refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to override onInterceptTouchEvent.  Its an odd function, documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate that, thanks.  I've just realised the problem is not "my" custom view, but all views -- I guess, the method I outlined for "turning off" a scroll view, is crap.  What a bummer.

Comment: Thanks Gabe - that's a great tip.  I'm pretty sure I'm just "all muddled up" but your tip is hugely useful.  I closed out the question to not waste anyone's time.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you want to override onInterceptTouchEvent to return false all the time if any view on screen is in drawing mode, and to return super.onInterceptTouchEvent if none are.  That should give you the behavior you want, providing your code to enter drawing mode works cleanly with this behavior.